# How to fake OS family in Ant through Cygwin

Tags: ant, cygwin

I have an **Ant** script which checks for the OS family

```
<os family="windows" />
```

and accordingly it is building my application. I would like to use **Cygwin** and i was expecting that when i invoke it via Cygwin then it will give me the Linux/Unix build, instead of the Windows one. But apparently this is not happening.

Am i able to somehow fake the OS when running through Cygwin ?

I have already tried to set the environment variable $OS to be Linux, but this didnt help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to put your specific linux tasks in its own target like that :

```
<target name="linuxbuild" if="islinuxbuild">
...
</target>
<target name="windowsbuild" unless="islinuxbuild">
...
</target>
```

and start your ant build for linux with :

```
ant -f yourbuild.xml -Dislinuxbuild=whatever
```

otherwise :

```
ant -f yourbuild.xml
```

Since Ant 1.8.x the if/unless attribute from target has been extended for additional flexibility, see [Ant manual if/unless attributes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless), but my example would still work with 
any ant version.

Comment: That is a good solutino indeed. My ant is invoked from Maven, but still i can pass the property value in mvn and this will be propagated to Ant.
    mvn -DisLinuxBuild=true clean install